# Angular Tooltip on Focus

Tags: angularjs, focus, tooltip

I'm using [Angular Tooltip](https://github.com/720kb/angular-tooltips) in my application and want to trigger tooltip on focus but having issue to trigger this. It works fine with `mouseover` and `mouseleave` but does not work on `focus` event.

here it is how I'm using it

```html
<input type="password"
   tooltip-show-trigger="focus"
   tooltips tooltip-template="Password must include at least one upper case letter, one lower case letter, one numeric digit and one special character."
   id="Password"
   name="Password"
   class="form-control"
   placeholder="New Password"
   required
   autofocus
   ng-model="Password" />
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong or missing something. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: I've never used this dependency, but since you have angular, can't you trigger the tooltip on the `ng-click` event manually ? So that when you click on your input, it triggers a custom function that calls your tooltip.

Comment: but focus can be with tab or enter navigation.. in that case ng-click will not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may help someone else...

`focus` isn't the actual event to trigger angular tooltip on focus. It is actually `focusin` and `focusout` according to [this issue discussion](https://github.com/720kb/angular-tooltips/issues/161). it resolved my issue.

```
 tooltip-show-trigger="focusin" tooltip-hide-trigger="focusout"
```